# Anything slider multiple images

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I usually use anything slider and it does the job perfectly, but this time my slider looks a little different. The slide panel show the image/video and a little part of the next image. Is this behavior possible with anything slider or should I search for another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the width and height of each panel (e.g. `li`) or elements within each panel (img, embed, iframe, etc).

If the panels are all the same size, then set the dimensions of the wrapper (e.g. `ul`) and make sure the `resizeContents` option is `true` ([ref](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Setup)).